# Magento Custom Module created_at and updated_at values

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9

I have created a custom module where in I need to save created_at and updated_at and display it in the grid in admin section.

I have created the table using:

```
created_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp, 
updated_at timestamp not null
```

And then in my controller I have added the below code:

```
$post_data['updated_at'] = now();
```

However, `created_at` saves time in my local zone (and not UTC) but `updated_at` saves time in UTC. How do we work about?

Comment: don't use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as it uses the timezone configured in mysql. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html + use your models  _beforeSave() function + Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate()